# Pointer or copy

Tags: go

I have the following Go code:

```
type Logger struct {
    Endpoint string
}

type Client struct {
    Logger Logger
}

func (c *Client) DoSomethingAwesome() {
    scopedLogger := c.Logger
    scopedLogger.LogSomethingAwesome()
}
```

And I cannot figure out if the `scopedLogger` variable that I am creating is a new instance or is it pointing to the same `Logger`?

Comment: All assignments are a copy in Go, but functionally it makes no difference here, as a shallow copy of `Logger` is identical for this purpose.

Comment: *"And I cannot figure out .... is a new instance or is it pointing to the same Logger?"* -- You can print the address of each to figure it out: https://play.golang.org/p/GBEtPMYmc5o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a new instance of the logger. If you want to point to the same Logger use pointer

```
func (c *Client) DoSomethingAwesome() {
    scopedLogger := &c.Logger
    scopedLogger.LogSomethingAwesome()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its a new instance you can verify that by printing memory address of each variable.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Logger struct {
    Endpoint string
}

type Client struct {
    Logger Logger
}

func (c *Client) DoSomethingAwesome() {
    scopedLogger := c.Logger
    p1 := &scopedLogger

    // print pointer
    fmt.Printf("p1: %p\n", p1)
}

func main() {
    cli := &Client{
        Logger: Logger{
            Endpoint: "something",
        },
    }

    p2 := &cli.Logger

    // print pointer
    fmt.Printf("p2: %p\n", p2)

    cli.DoSomethingAwesome()
}

/* output
p2: 0xc000096220
p1: 0xc000096230
*/
```